# Restrict the Firebase Database to accept only unique email IDs on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a list of authenticated users and I want the Firebase to accept email ID only if that email ID isn't in use or does not exist in my Firebase Database.

I searched for answers before asking this question, but none of the ones that I have seen has helped me to tackle this problem.

I am using Google for authentication and I am storing the emails on Firebase in **"Authenticated-Users"** .

This has also created second problem for me: when I **sign out** and then **sign in** again with the same user, the email ID is duplicated and added to the Firebase again.

Here are the rules I have applied but which are not working:
[image: Firebase rules applied]

Here is my database; as you can see, the same user is added twice:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> i want the Firebase to accept, only if that emailId isn't in use or does not exist on Firebase database.

When you authenticate using any method(email,google..) provided by Firebase, then the email will be in the Firebase console after the user signs up. Therefore if the email is in the console, then if another user tried to sign up using that email, they can't since it exists in the authenticated console.

This is done by Firebase authentication(so you do not have to do it).

You can test this by using this `Toast` on signup:

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Authentication Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It will show you the error (example email exists).

---

To check if the email exists in the database:

```
   DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Authenticated-Users");

    ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo(anemailhere).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

       @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

           }
          }
     @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out here,This solution worked for me.
God bless you.

Comment: Hello, this solution seems to be not working for me anymore, It was working fine for some times but now it doesn't work. I do not get any error or any app crashes though, i din't even bring any change in the code.

Comment: do you have any alternative answer for this question ?

Comment: which one as it is two parts? Also just keep the rules in the console as auth!=null for both read and write. Don't add !newData.child("email").exists() as firebase checks if the email is in the console

Comment: sir, i din't modify anything,this solution kind of stopped working for me .

Comment: if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

           } 
it always returns false even if the email ids exist.

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi they need to exist in your database

Comment: Yes they exist, right now i have 5 same email IDs but still it returns false.

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi the above should work.. make sure u did not change anything as u said it was working.. also add an else with a toast inside of it just to be sure what is happening

Comment: Okay but I'll be grateful if you find me another solution for this.Thanks

Comment: really this is the only way.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45451037/7015400. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists().  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38573894/7015400. If it was working then u changed something that is why it stopped working as I said add an `else{` inside of it add a `Toast` or Log to check if it entering

Comment: This time I put name instead of email in **orderByChild("name")** , it returns true if that name exists.
but weirdly, stopped working for **email**.

Comment: in the equalTo there should be an email not a name if the orderByChild is an email

Comment: You are right, but since the **email** stopped working for me , i started using **name**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164565/discussion-between-niamatullah-bakhshi-and-peter-haddad).